# Angular JS cannot register the controller

Tags: angularjs

I've got a really simple Angular JS application, and I cannot figure out why I'm getting an error: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CoursesController' is not a function, got undefined

My fiddle (you'll need to open up your browser dev tools to see error in console): http://jsfiddle.net/Y4c2q/

My Angular JS code:

```
'use strict';
console.log('reg module entry');
var registrationModule = angular.module('registrationModule', []);

registrationModule.controller('CoursesController', function ($scope, bootStrappedData) {
    $scope.courses = bootStrappedData.courses;
    console.log('inside of controller');
});

registrationModule.factory('bootStrappedData', function() {
    console.log('bootstrapping our data');
    return {
courses: [{"number":"aaa","name":"magical creatures","instructor":"John"},
          {"number":"bbb","name":"ze dark arts","instructor":"Rob"},
          {"number":"ccc","name":"third book","instructor":"Bran"}]
     };
});
```

this is the HTML where I want to display my 3 rows of data:

```
<div ng-controller="CoursesController">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>Course</th>
            <th>Course Name</th>
            <th>Instructor</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="course in courses">
            <td>{{course.number}}</td>
            <td>{{course.name}}</td>
            <td>{{course.instructor}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How is you application bootstrapped? Via `ng-app` or manually? Is `registrationModule` marked as dependency for main application module?

Comment: Did you checked my fiddle? If I understood your question correctly, according to this link (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) I'm pretty sure I've used automatic bootstrapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is coming because your ng-app declaration is missing the module name. Use this

`ng-app='registrationModule'`

This would link the your modules and controller to the view.